# Enforcing Saas subscription requirements for client based apps

Tags: google-chrome-extension, saas

I want to create a SaaS extension for chrome.

How do I ensure that they cannot use my extension's functionality when their subscription is no longer current?

My basic idea is that whenever they want to use my chrome extension's functionality, the extension makes an ajax request to my server to check to see if today's date is before the subscription's ending date in my DB.

The extension is obviously is client based, so even if I have code on the client side that's only executed if my ajax request returns that they have a current subscription, couldn't an enterprising individual just look at my code and run it via console in a way that gets past my ajax request requirement?

Is there a way to enforce the subscription?

Edit:

This is mostly a conceptual question, but I'll try be clearer.

All the javascript code needed for my app to function is on their local machine, in their source files (to work it doesn't require access to my database).

so you could think of my code on their local machine as looking like this:

```
if (usersSubscriptionIsCurrent) {
  runFeature()
}
```

And usersSubscriptionIsCurrent is true if the Ajax request to my server returns that their subscription is current.

Someone could still run my feature just by looking at the source code, and then typing `runFeature()` into their console.

I want to prevent that.

My extension relies on sending data from the extension to a related chrome app, so I just had the idea that I could also send the data to my server, which could then forward the data to user's chrome app if they have a current subscription. But yikes.

The more I think about it, the less I think it's possible for me to prevent, but I figured I'd ask in case anyone has a clever idea.

Comment: Could you attach some related code about this issue?

Comment: edited, hopefully made it clearer

Comment: Is your extension need to pay? Here's a reference towards your issue. You might track a "subscription_active" boolean or similar on the User model. When a user logs in, you can check against the API to see the status of a user's subscription. To see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085777/what-is-the-best-way-to-prevent-user-from-using-saas-app-after-failed-payment

Comment: My point is that even if the API says their subscription is over, they can just look at my extensions source code, find the function they want to run, and run it via console, bypassing my subscription check.

Comment: I have no idea you could prevent them to do it on their local files if all the javascript files needed for the app to function is on the users' local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are slightly confused about what counts as SaaS. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service):

> Software as a service is a software licensing and delivery model in which software is licensed on a subscription basis and **is centrally hosted**. SaaS is typically accessed by users using a **thin client** via a web browser.

Emphasis mine.

If your app / extension contains all the logic required, it does not qualify as SaaS. Futhermore, as it is always possible to copy/dissect your app, taking out all license checks, you can't protect it against a determined attacker.

There are ways to protect your code to some degree, via obfuscation, offloading logic to [(P)NaCl](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/portable-native-client-pinnacle-of.html) modules, [native host modules](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), or, as Alex Belozerov [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997279/934239), load the code on runtime. Again, all of that can be broken by a determined attacker.

But if you truly have SaaS in mind (and not just subscription-based licensing), your client app should be a **thin client**: that is, your app logic should be processed on a server, with code safely away from clients. That is the only "sure" way to protect it, but incurs processing costs to you, but that's what subscription is supposed to cover in the first place.

Comment: I did have a subscription based service in mind, but you're right I guess mine doesn't count as SaaS. In my personal case, offloading logic to my server doesn't really help me, so I'll need to pivot. Thanks Xan

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best solution is to check if their subscription is current as soon as the extension starts, and then use the [chrome management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management) to uninstall or disable it if their subscription is over.

I'd love to hear better ideas though.

Comment: That will not stop a very, very determined attacker from copying the source from Chrome profile while the subscription is still valid, modify it, and load it unpacked, for instance. Note that recently Chrome started blocking local modifications to Store-installed items though

Comment: So it may work and it may not? Do you have a link to where they talk about blocking local modifications? There should be a way to hide code right? Otherwise any chrome app or extension could just be copied and sold by anyone else (ignoring copyright laws...)

Comment: Yes, you can always copy code. For SaaS your ONLY solution is offloading logic to a server. I don't have a link, but Chrome enforces file hashes on CRX-installed extensions as malware protection - if you edit a file in an installed extension, it will get disabled. But you can copy it and load as unpacked.

Comment: P.S.: here's where I learned it, but I don't have a Chrome dev blog link to confirm: https://github.com/cezarsa/silver_bird/issues/427

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the link, it did help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get part of code needed from server side. So if user's subscription is over, he won't be apple to run your feature as part of code is missing. Concept of my idea:

```
var subscriptionStatusResponse = makeAjaxCall();
if(subscriptionStatusResponse.usersSubscriptionIsCurrent) {
   runFeature_localCode();                  // only part of functional
   subscriptionStatusResponse.remoteCode(); // second part
}
```

Comment: possible, but most likely unwise. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471753/pass-javascript-function-in-ajax-response

Comment: Also they can just check the network tab and copy it for later use.